# Are players expected to perception roll every new room in an area?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, dice, exploration

Every room, cave, shop and location has a description the GM reads out.

To access the full details availible, are perception checks required to be made constantly at the request of the party?

I want players to fully interact with their environments/NPCs and avoid missing content.

Answer (score 8):

## The Flavor Text Boxes Don't Need a Roll

In Paizo's published adventures, most new areas (such as the next room in a dungeon) have flavor text near the top. This is meant to be read aloud to the players as they enter the room, **without a Perception check.** This flavor text is set aside visually in some way. The rest of the room's description will list anything that *needs* Perception (or something else) to find; the GM may roll some of those automatically if the PC's are [Searching](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=519) (i.e. using the Search exploration activity).

## From the Player's Perspective

Generally, when you are going room by room, you'll be in [Exploration mode](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=469). During this mode, as a player, you get to choose an [Exploration activity](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=471) to be performing; the aforementioned [Search](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=519) is one of these. Your GM will (should) roll [Secret Checks](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=334) using [Perception](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=326) to find secret door, items, or hazards (think traps) for you. Otherwise, as a player, if you are curious about the room, then you should ask your GM if you can roll a Perception check. As described in the Search activity:

> In locations with many objects to search, you have to stop and spend significantly longer to search thoroughly.

In practice, this is only for things like dungeons, in which you might expect things to be hidden in rooms. Even then, I've only generally seen my players do it when they are looking for a specific something, or when they enter a suspicious room (like a tomb, treasure vault, armory, etc.). As GM, I tend to wave my players off if there isn't anything to find, so in practice it doesn't really slow down play.

Comment: I would rephrase your last line, and give it it's own heading. Based on OP's recent questions, it seems to me that they are pretty new to the system and could benefit from it being very clear that Searching *should* allow the PC's to have Secret Perception rolls performed by the GM (or else have the GM call for them if they don't like the Secret roll rules) for each instance where they *could* find something. It would also make the answer more complete than just addressing prewritten AP's

Comment: @Ifusaso I added a section, thoughts on that?